# How to apply excerpt length only on front end?

Tags: excerpt, review, theme-review

I have a theme on WordPress theme review queue and I'm using the below code to change excerpt length.

```
function theme_slug_excerpt_length( $length ) {
    return 50;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'theme_slug_excerpt_length', 999 );
```

Now theme reviewer ask to apply that limit on only front end, which is it should not impact on admin side.

So will this below code work?

```
function theme_slug_excerpt_length( $length ) {
    if ( is_admin() ) {
        return $length;
    }
    return 50;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'theme_slug_excerpt_length', 999 );
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Regards
Ponvendhan

Comment: Yes, the filters only show on the front end. They'll still be able to enter longer excerpts in wp-admin.

Comment: You could simplify your code to `return is_admin() ? $length : 50`;. Are you allowed to modify the rest-api response from theme files? It looks like `is_admin()` will not prevent that. Note how the TwentyTen and TwentyEleven use the `excerpt_length` filter without any restrictions.